# API working fine on Postman but not returning anything on android app

Tags: android, wordpress, api, android-volley

I am making an app for a Wordpress website using the WP REST API V2. I am able to retrieve the category data using the API, but when I try to retrieve posts or media, nothing happens.

```
 private void sendJsonRequest(){
    Log.i("Warlock","Entered sendJsonRequest");
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_XBOX,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.i("Warlock","Entered onResponse");

            try {
                Log.i("Warlock",response.toString());
                parseJsonArray(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}


private void parseJsonArray(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
    Log.i("Warlock","Entered parseJsonArray");

    if (response == null || response.length() == 0){
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < response.length(); i++){

        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
        int id = Integer.getInteger(jsonObject.getString(KEY_ID));
        //String title = jsonObject.getString(KEY_TITLE);

        JSONObject jsonTitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_TITLE);
        JSONObject jsonContent = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_CONTENT);
        JSONObject jsonExcerpt = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_EXCERPT);


        String title = jsonTitle.getString("rendered");
        String content = jsonContent.getString("rendered");
        String excerpt = jsonExcerpt.getString("rendered");
        String featuredMedia = jsonObject.getString(KEY_FEATURED_MEDIA);
        WordPressPost newPost = new WordPressPost();

        newPost.setId(id);
        newPost.setTitle(title);
        newPost.setContent(content);
        newPost.setExcrept(excerpt);
        newPost.setFeaturedMedia(featuredMedia);
        listPosts.add(newPost);

    }
    Log.i("Warlock",listPosts.toString());
    text.setText(listPosts.toString());



}
```

Here is the log output:

```
05-04 05:31:10.374 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.warlock31.badcontroller-1/lib/x86
05-04 05:31:11.350 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.warlock31.badcontroller-1/lib/x86
05-04 05:31:11.564 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller I/Warlock: Constructor Called
05-04 05:31:11.596 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
[ 05-04 05:31:11.600 26586:26586 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe7c93d70, tid 26586
05-04 05:31:11.630 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller I/Warlock: Entered sendJsonRequest
05-04 05:31:11.649 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
05-04 05:31:11.650 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-04 05:31:11.656 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
[ 05-04 05:31:11.662 26586:26640 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf0477340, tid 26640
05-04 05:31:11.679 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-04 05:31:11.776 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-04 05:31:11.776 26586-26640/com.warlock31.badcontroller W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe0b87e80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-04 05:31:11.828 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
05-04 05:31:11.859 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
[ 05-04 05:31:12.034    87:   87 D/         ]
Socket deconnection
```

Comment: I assume you are using Google Volley. Could you post your log outputs for running this part of your application? Only after then we could tell you more about your issue. Thanks!

Comment: since `Entered onResponse` dose not appear in logs, so i assume `onErrorResponse()` was called, and you have no logs in there, add log to the error, also show us the URL you are calling (if it's not confidential)

Comment: also in logs it says `RecyclerView: No adapter attached` make sure you have set the adapter to the RecyclerView object

Comment: This is the error i am getting.

`code 05-04 05:43:03.314 26586-26586/com.warlock31.badcontroller I/Warlock: com.android.volley.TimeoutError `

Comment: yes, that's why i asked you to show the URL, is it `http://localhost...` ???

Comment: The api url is http://www.badcontroller.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

Comment: So i figured out the solution. Turns out, the posts i am retrieving contains huge amount of data and hence the timeout. I used the following code to solve it.
    `code request.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {

            @Override
            public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

            }
        }); `